# Tile based game (Unity), inaccurate readings of mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: X marks the top of cursor when clicked]

**X** marks the top of the cursor when the tile was clicked.

The tile below was the one that was set.

**The code that I am using to read the position of the mouse when it was clicked:**

```
Vector3 rayPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);   
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (
    new Vector2 (rayPos.x, rayPos.y),
    new Vector2 (0f, 1f));
```

Does anybody have a theory of why this happened?

Comment: Unity had an answer to this question [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/331558/screentoworldpoint-not-working.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hi as Steven said use ScreenPointToRay() method

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 position;
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 20000)) {
    position = hit.point;
} else {
  // do something when no hit
}
```